# SASS based semantic fluid grid

Tags: css, sass

I am looking for opinions on this code. I have been experimenting with SASS the last few days and have come up with the following code. The idea was to enable the creation of a fluid grid without having non-semantic markup in the HTML.

```
$columns: 12; //total number of columns to use
$gutter: 3%; // gutter width can be any unit
$column_width: 5.3333%; // column width can be any unit

// calculated total width
$total_width: $columns * ($gutter + $column_width);

// Sub-pixel fix for IE http://tylertate.com/blog/2012/01/05/subpixel-rounding.html
// min width in pixels, do not append px to the number.
$min_width: 480;
$ie_correction: (.5 / $min_width) * 100 * 1%;


// calculate width of a column based on it's span.
@function width( $span ) {
        @return ( $span * $column_width ) + ( $gutter * ( $span - 1 ) );
}

// micro clearfix hack 
// http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/
@mixin clearfix {
        &:before,
        &:after {
                content: "";
                display: table;
        }
        &:after {
                clear: both;
        }
        *zoom:1;
}

// Sets up a container for individual columns
@mixin row() {
        display: block;
        width: $total_width*(($gutter + width($columns))/width($columns));
        margin: 0 $total_width*((($gutter*.5)/width($columns))*-1);
        *width: $total_width*(($gutter + width($columns))/width($columns)) - $ie_correction;
        *margin: 0 ($total_width*((($gutter*.5)/width($columns))*-1)) - $ie_correction;
        @include clearfix;      
}

// Sets single column and determins the offset distance and direction.
//
// $span: default 1; Determins the width of the column;
// $type: default none; has three available options
//        push: pushes column to the right by the specified amount of columns
//        pull: pulls a column to the left by a specified amount of columns
//        center: centers a column of the desired size in the container
//
// $offset: default 0; determines the amount by which push and pull offset the column
// $last: default false; if true the column will be floated to the right; 

@mixin column( $span: 1, $type: none, $offset: 0, $last:false ) {
        @if $last == true {
                float: right;
        } @else {
                float: left;
        }
        width: width( $span );
        *width: width($span) - $ie_correction;
        @if $type == none {
                margin: 0 $gutter / 2;
                *margin: 0 (( $gutter / 2 ) - $ie_correction );
        } @else if $type == push {
                margin: 0 ( $gutter / 2 ) 0 ( width( $offset ) + ( $gutter * 1.5 ) );
                *margin: 0 ( ( $gutter / 2 ) - $ie_correction ) 0 ( width( $offset ) + ( $gutter * 1.5 ) - $ie_correction );
        } @else if $type == pull {
                margin: 0 ( width( $offset ) + ( $gutter * 1.5 ) ) 0 ( $gutter / 2 );
                *margin: 0 ( width( $offset ) + ( $gutter * 1.5 ) - $ie_correction ) 0 ( ( $gutter / 2 ) - $ie_correction );
        } @else if $type == center {
                diplay: block;
                width: width( $span );
                margin: 0 auto; 
                float: none !important;
        }
}

// Used to order columns right-to-left. Sets single column and determins the offset distance and direction.
//
// $span: default 1; Determins the width of the column;
// $type: default none; has three available options
//        push: pushes column to the right by the specified amount of columns
//        pull: pulls a column to the left by a specified amount of columns
//        center: centers a column of the desired size in the container
//
// $offset: default 0; determines the amount by which push and pull offset the column
// $last: default false; if true the column will be floated to the right; 

@mixin column_right( $span: 1, $type: none, $offset: 0, $last:false ) {
        @if $last == true {
                float: left;
        } @else {
                float: right;
        }
        width: width( $span );
        *width: width($span) - $ie_correction;
        @if $type == none {
                margin: 0 $gutter / 2;
                *margin: 0 (( $gutter / 2 ) - $ie_correction ) 0 (( $gutter / 2 ) - $ie_correction );
        } @else if $type == push {
                margin: 0 ( width( $offset ) + ( $gutter * 1.5 ) ) 0 ( $gutter / 2 ) ;
                *margin: 0 ( width( $offset ) + ( $gutter * 1.5 ) - $ie_correction ) 0 ( $gutter / 2 );
        } @else if $type == pull {
                margin: 0 ( $gutter / 2 ) 0 ( width( $offset ) + ( $gutter * 1.5 ) );
                *margin: 0 ( ( $gutter / 2 ) - $ie_correction ) 0 ( width( $offset ) + ( $gutter * 1.5 ) - $ie_correction );
        } @else if $type == center {
                diplay: block;
                width: width( $span );
                margin: 0 auto; 
                float: none !important;
        }
}


// Creates a grid from an elements children. By default it is designed to work
// on a unordered list, but it can work with any element type chosed by the 
// $element variable.
//
// $width: default 4; defines with amount of elemeents per row
// $margin: default $gutter variable; sets margin between each item
// $element: default li; defines the type element to target
@mixin grid( $width:4, $margin:$gutter, $element:li ) {
        @include clearfix;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-left: -#{$margin};
        clear: both;
        & > #{$element} {
                float: left;
                display: block;
                width: ( $total_width / $width ) - $margin;
                margin: 0 0 $margin $margin;
                *width: ( $total_width / $width ) - $margin - $ie_correction;
                *margin: 0 0 ( $margin - $ie_correction ) ( $margin - $ie_correction );
                &:nth-child( #{$width}n + #{$width}) {
                        float: right;
                }
        }
}
```

Implementation is pretty straight forward.

```
column(5); // 5 column width ordered left to right
column(3, push, 3); //3 column width, pushing 3 columns from left
column(3, pull, 3); // 3 column width, pulling 3 columns from right
column(3, push, 2, true); // 3 columns, pushing 2 from left, and floated right as last column in row

column_right(5); // 5 columns ordered right to left
column_right(4, push, 3); //5 columns, right-to-left, pushing 3column widths from right

grid(4); // creates for a four up grid when applied to a ul, applies default margin
grid(5, 1%, div) // creates a five up grid with a 1% margin, which is applied to all child div elements.
```

I'm looking for opinions on what I can do better, and whether you think I'm overcomplicating the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating the whole thing. I have been building responsive design layouts for years, and there are really just not that many scenarios when a robust 'grid-system' isn't more work than it's worth. There isn't ever a 1 column area in a 12 column grid for example.

In my experience, there are big areas (almost like mini layouts) in your larger layout. Within those, you can stack things, and then with @media queries, float them into columns when it suites you. Then when at it's largest break-point, you can start using absolute positioning and stuff if you want to lock into a really specific layout.

Then the other situation is an actual grid of items or photos etc. That is a good time to have a little solution to split the chunks up, but really... how many do you have? 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 columns of things? Splitting them with percentages is the way to go, but depending on your markup, the gutters can be a challenge.

I have taken a few stabs at a simple grid, but they all have their own caveats. Using min and max widths for break-points can alleviate the need to overwrite nth-of-type rules. My latest favorite way to deal is to margin-right all list-items, then the actual item is usually a link - so a display block link... then the trick is to translate the whole list over to the left a little... anyways -

I think you'll find more cases where your 'grid' doesn't work than where is works perfectly and my suggestion is to break your ideas into a few different pieces.

This is my most recent build: http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/azRpRM